# Using TeX fonts in HTML documents?

Tags: fonts, html

If I want to use TeX fonts (such as cmr10, cmbx10, cmtt10, and so forth) in my HTML documents, what are the recommended ways to do that?

As a thought experiment and proof-of-concept, this afternoon I re-encoded the 140 fonts from the bakoma-fonts package as web fonts and made a font waterfall demonstration page:

- [Using TeX Fonts in HTML](http://disco.bu.edu/~tsl/using-tex-fonts-in-html/)

The results are encouraging, but I don't know if this is the best way to achieve this. I still need to organize the various sizes and shapes into font families in the CSS style sheet and add CSS classes for invoking the various weights, shapes, and sizes.

I hope I'm not reinventing the wheel here, but I started down this path today because I was unsuccessful in finding any other resources about this topic anywhere. It seems that lots of people want to use fancy TrueType fonts in TeX documents, but I seem to be the only one who wants to use native TeX fonts in my web pages. Is this a road to Hell paved with good intentions and nothing but insanity at the end of the rainbow? I know that ligatures are going to be difficult and that obviously hyphenation is going to work differently, but I still think it would be really fun to use Computer Modern Roman and friends in some of my HTML documents, and the challenge of getting there is so tempting.

Comment: Any update on your progress? I also wanted to make TeX fonts work well in the browser, particularly the default Knuth's Computer Modern. Did you ever reached the point where a PDF made from the webpage would be indistinguishable from one output using pdflatex? I made this tex account just to ask you a question here. I don't have enough points to comment, you haven't listed your email address in your profile and there's no private messaging system. My email address is colmsloan@gmail.com. Feel free to delete this answer after you've read it.

Comment: @ColmSloan — About all the farther I got is this:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44486/pixel-perfect-vertical-alignment-of-image-rendered-tex-snippets

Comment: Link in post is dead.

Comment: @DavidGiven — Fixed the URL... thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you specifically want the Computer Modern fonts on your webpage, your best bet is to use the [Latin Modern](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/index_html) CM clone, since it is available in OTF format. These could then be used e.g. with `@font-face` (Fontsquirrel has [a good generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)).

If you're asking a more general question, e.g. "How do I use any T1 font on my webpage", the answer is a bit more depressing. In that case, your only option would be to generate an OTF font based on the T1 representations. This is nontrivial and presumably time-consuming, but it should be possible using FontForge or similar tools.

**tl;dr:** Find an OTF alternative if possible, otherwise create an OTF font based on the T1 fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the Latin Modern collection, @You. I converted all of those and created a CSS style sheet for them, and now my HTML documents look almost like TeX output. It was a *lot* of work to make get the CSS operational, but it was worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Someone created a project which allows you to have LaTeX fonts inside your HTML. Include the following in the head of your html page, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font/master/fonts.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Computer Modern Sans", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

I used it for my own purposes and it is working well.
As a side note, the [documentation says that it is safe](https://github.com/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font) to rely on this external css.